# Error while installing node-expat in mac (python not found)

Tags: node.js, npm, node-expat

In my mac M1 (running on rosetta emulation), I get the following error while installing node-expat package.

```
santhosh.kulandaiyan@santhosh Backend % npm i node-expat

> node-expat@2.4.0 install /Users/santhosh.kulandaiyan/code/ps/euler-ps/Backend/node_modules/node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild

  CC(target) Release/obj.target/expat/deps/libexpat/lib/xmlparse.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/expat/deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/expat/deps/libexpat/lib/xmlrole.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/libexpat.a
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/libexpat.a] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/santhosh.kulandaiyan/code/ps/euler-ps/Backend/node_modules/node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-expat@2.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.4.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/santhosh.kulandaiyan/.npm/_logs/2022-05-12T11_57_35_997Z-debug.log
```

My node versions are below and python 3 is indeed available as a environment variable and also in the PATH.

```
node --version
v14.17.6

npm --version
6.14.15

printenv | grep python
PYTHON=/usr/bin/python

python --version
Python 3.8.9
```

It looks like node-expat doesn't directly depend on python as per
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-expat

I am unable to figure out why exactly it is complaining that python is not found.
And if I look at the verbose output, then the last few lines just complain about npm i node-expat failing..

```
74 78 verbose stack Error: node-expat@2.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
3175 78 verbose stack Exit status 1
3176 78 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
3177 78 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
3178 78 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
3179 78 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
3180 78 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
3181 78 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
3182 79 verbose pkgid node-expat@2.4.0
3183 80 verbose cwd /Users/santhosh.kulandaiyan/code/ps/euler-ps/Backend
3184 81 verbose Darwin 21.4.0
3185 82 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "node-expat"
3186 83 verbose node v14.17.6
3187 84 verbose npm  v6.14.15
3188 85 error code ELIFECYCLE
3189 86 error errno 1
3190 87 error node-expat@2.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
3191 87 error Exit status 1
3192 88 error Failed at the node-expat@2.4.0 install script.
3193 88 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
3194 89 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help with this please!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this exact issue as soon as I narrowed it down to a `node-gyp` specific one.

The `node-gyp` readme has steps for Mac. [This document has all the details](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/main/macOS_Catalina.md), but is confusingly called `Installation notes for macOS Catalina (v10.15)`. That might throw you off. [The main readme](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-macos) is more correct it says:

> If your Mac has been upgraded to macOS Catalina (10.15) or higher, please read macOS_Catalina.md.

I did the following to get it all to work based on the info on these pages:

1. I verified I had a compatible version of Python installed: `Python v3.7, v3.8, v3.9, or v3.10`
2. I verified `XCode Command Line Tools` were installed
3. I installed `node-gyp` `npm install -g node-gyp` this will give you the path where it installs `node-gyp`
4. Then I did `npm config set node_gyp <path to node-gyp>`

After that `npm i node-expat` and `npm i` worked again.